# Working with Google in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to use Google in app billing in my app. My code dose not have any error in eclipse but when I run it on my phone it force closes! and log cat points error to "new Thread" line. what is the problem? I'll be thankful if someone could help.

Here is my code:

in onCreate under donate button:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        skuList.add("My Selling Obj ID");
                        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
                        querySkus.putStringArrayList("My App’s RSA Key"
                                , skuList);

                        Bundle skuDetails;
                        try {
                            skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
                            int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                            if (response == 0) {
                               ArrayList<String> responseList
                                  = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                               for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                                  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                                  String sku = object.getString("productId");
                                  String price = object.getString("price");
                                  if (sku.equals("My Selling Obj ID"))
                                      pool = price;
                               }
                            }

                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                        Bundle buyIntentBundle;
                        try {
                            buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
                                       "My Selling Obj ID", "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                                       1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                       Integer.valueOf(0));
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                  }).start();
            }
```

in onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
       if (requestCode == 1001) {           
          int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
          String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
          String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "thanks for Donation!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, pool, 
                isdonated = 1;
              }
              catch (JSONException e) {
                 //alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                 Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Donation Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

here is logcat errors:
http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-02/08566691322028747175.jpg

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have post picture of my logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this permission to you manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Comment: please add this permission in manifest file <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>

Comment: [Ref](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) for in app billing.

Comment: I have added this permission. Is it possible to test this during developing OR I should upload it to market and then they do some actions on server to make it possible?

Comment: Yes its possible to test while developing check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html) for reference.